# How to install Windows 2012 on Dell server with S110 RAID?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, dell

I have a Dell server that has a S110 software RAID 1 mirror for the boot disks.  When I run the Windows 2012 installer, no drives are found.  I searched Dell for drivers but the only one I found for S110 is an .exe file which is unusable during installation.  How can I get the drives to show up at installation?  Is it even worth it to use the S110 software RAID or should I just use the drive mirroring capability already in Windows?

Comment: Is this a newer Dell?  If so try booting to the Lifecycle controller in order to initiate the OS install.

Comment: Aha thanks, I'm reading about this Lifecycle controller and it sounds very promising.  There is an OS deployment page (I'm new to Dell servers).  I have to go back to the colocation facility to test as I don't have a KVM over IP.

Comment: Im nota an of it but it is Dells new Open Manage cd replacement.  Took me forever to figure it out the first time.

Comment: This thing is so crazy.  So I didn't get an optical drive or iDrac...there is no way to install with Lifecycle controller.  I'm going to have to go back to the office and try a USB CD-ROM because you aren't allowed to install from USB flash with Lifecycle controller.

Comment: What kind of server is this?  Check the BIOS settings and make sure that the settings allow USB hard drive emulation.  It should allow you to boot from a USB drive as I've done it with some of ours.

Comment: I have booted from USB flash no problem, but I can't install Windows 2012 that way because the Perc 110 controller driver is only available when doing an OS Deploy from the Lifecycle controller.  The Lifecycle controller only allows OS Deploy from CD/DVD or iDRAC.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Probably need the usb cd drive then

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the integrated version found here: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=FNPHT

Unfortunately, it let me delete all the partitions but not install windows from a flash drive.  It saw the disks individually (not the logical disk from the RAID) but would not allow installation on either disk.  Tried the Lifecycle controller, but did not see the iso on the flash drive (not that I expected it too).  I'm trying to get away from burning discs for everything, but not this time I guess.